# Joomla Database - How to use LIMIT in getQuery?

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla3.1

I want to build the below query using joomla inbuilt database class.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This is the query I have built up to now.

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();       
$query  = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->nameQuote('*'));
$query->from($db->nameQuote(TABLE_PREFIX.'table_name'));      
$db->setQuery($query);      
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
```

I don't know how to add the limit(LIMIT 1) to the query. Can someone please tell me how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 46, accepted):

## Older than Joomla 3.0

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();    

$query  = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*')
 ->from($db->nameQuote('#__table_name'))
 ->order($db->nameQuote('id').' desc');     
$db->setQuery($query,0,1);  

$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
```

`$db->setQuery` function takes 3 parameters. The first one being the query, then the start, then the limit. We can limit records as shown above.

## Newer than Joomla 3.0

```
setLimit(integer $limit, integer $offset)
```

If you want just one row

```
$query->setLimit(1);
```

[Read more](http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseQueryLimitable.html)

Comment: this is strange (I will try to find out why) older method works with J3.3.1 but newer method doesn't.

Comment: Krzysztof Jarosz - I'm also having the same issue of setLimit() not working with Joomla 3.3.2.

Answer (score 4):

This should work as well:

```
$query->setLimit(1);
```

Documentation: http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseQueryLimitable.html

Comment: since Joomla 3.0 (Platform 12.1)

Answer (score 3):

SetLimit doesn't work for me in Joomla 3.4.x, so try:

Within the model:

```
protected function getListQuery()
{
    // Create a new query object.
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    // Select some fields
    $query->select('*');
    $query->from('#__your_table');

    $this->setState('list.limit', 0); // 0 = unlimited

    return $query;
}
```

Davids answer: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4249/model-getlistquery-fetch-all-rows-with-using-jpagination

> Run that before the model calls getItems and it will load all the
>   items for you.
>
> A few caveats with this.
>
> You can also do this outside the model, so if for instance you were in
>   your view. You could do the following:
>
> $model = $this->getModel(); $model->setState('list.limit', 0);
>
> Sometimes you can do this too early, before the model's state has been
>   populated, which will cause the model to get rebuilt from the user
>   state after you have set the limit, basically overriding the limit.
>
> To fix this, you can force the model to populate its state first:
>
> $model = $this->getModel(); $model->getState();
>   $model->setState('list.limit', 0); The actual populateState method is
>   protected, so outside the model you can't call it directly, but any
>   call to getState will make sure that the populateState is called
>   before returning the current settings in the state.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Just had to revisit this answer, and I can confirm, both the methods
`setLimit` & `order` are working if used as below.

```
$query->order($db->qn($data->sort_column_name) . ' ' . $data->sort_column_order);
$query->setLimit($length,$start);
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

As of 08/Sept/14 The solutions from @Dasun or @escopecz arent working for me on J3.x

but this old trick is working for me which is nice,

```
  $query->order($db->qn('id') . ' DESC LIMIT 25');
```

And About your specific requirement of wishing to [**fetch only 1 row**](http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#loadObject.28.29) you could use :

```
  $rows = $db->loadObject();
```

Comment: @mickmackusa I absolutely agree correct usage should be followed, Its just that at that time (*almost 5 years ago*), I was unable to use the methods in question and was pretty frustrated, and upon finally discovering a workaround, I just posted it here hoping maybe it could help someone out in a similar situation.